# CollapsiblePanelExtender not work in IE

Tags: dotnetnuke-module

in DotNetNuke module,i tried CollapsiblePanelExtender, it work fine with FF,it alway explan with IE?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the doctype for your skin is correct - this was something i ran into a lot.

Might also suggest you use jQuery to get the same effect its lighter and actually easier to use.